# Memory loss in multi-threaded wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, out-of-memory

The scenario is as follows: an application with several threads: 2 to request data from different sources, 3 to update different information on the screen, and 1 to play audios on demand.
The problem: the application has to work non-stop, and when starting it works fine, but after a while (not always the same, usually between 5 and 8 hours) it ends up failing. The error trace points
to one of the painting threads, where I get the exception "System.OutOfMemoryException" for 5 or 6 minutes, until finally the program stops. That thread runs inside two others, which are 2 animations (fadeIn, fadeOut) that last 1sec, before and after updating the information. If I remove those animations the program does not fail (at least 24 hours). I would like to keep the animations, and help to detect what I am doing wrong, I suppose I am not releasing resources or something similar.

I have look at two things:

1) Application Memory: I have created this variable

`PerformanceCounter ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");"`

and in each thread pass I execute it this way:

`"RAM disponible: " + ramCounter.NextValue() + "MB"`

The value is always around 3.5/4Gb, so it doesn't seem to be losing memory.

2) Number of threads: I read that there is a limit of threads that an application can create, and I thought that if I was not closing them properly maybe that was the problem. But it does not seem either. I execute this on each thread pass and it always gives me a stable value between 30 and 35:

`"NumThreads: "+System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count"`

I attach the code, and see if you can tell me what I'm doing wrong:

Thread that paints information (if I remove the lines of the animations the application works ok)

```
while (true){
try{
    EscribirLogError("PintarTiempos - RAM disponible: " + ramCounter.NextValue() + "MB",false);
    tiempoPrevisiones = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TIEMPOPREVS"]);

    //Animación quitar tiempos
    tFadeOut = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FadeOut));
    tFadeOut.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    tFadeOut.Start();
    //Pintar tiempos
    this.window.pintaTiempos(previsiones);
    Console.WriteLine("NumThreads: " + System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);
    EscribirLogError("NumThreads: "+System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count,false);
    //Animación tiempos nuevos
    tFadeIn = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FadeIn));
    tFadeIn.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    tFadeIn.Start();

    Thread.Sleep(tiempoPrevisiones * 1000);

}catch(Exception e){
    EscribirLogError("PintaTiempos:" + e.Message, true);
}

public void FadeIn()
    {
        TimeSpan fadeInTime = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:01");
        Double opacityFinalFadeIn = 1d;
        Thread.Sleep(750);
        this.window.FadeIn(fadeInTime, opacityFinalFadeIn);
    }`
```

The fadeIn function from instance this.window

```
public void FadeIn(TimeSpan fadeInTime, Double d)
{
  this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new System.Action(() =>
  {
    try
    {
        var fadeInAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(1d, fadeInTime);
        for (int i = 0; i < this.lblTiempos.Length; i++)
        {
            this.lblLineas[i].BeginAnimation(Label.OpacityProperty, fadeInAnimation);
            this.lblDestinos[i].BeginAnimation(Label.OpacityProperty, fadeInAnimation);
            this.lblTiempos[i].BeginAnimation(Label.OpacityProperty, fadeInAnimation);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        this.programa.EscribirLogError("FadeIn.Dispatcher:" + e.Message, true);
    }
  }), null);
}
```

I put this info about timers and events at the request of the user @Kelly:

```
//Timers definition
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer time;
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer wakeup; 

//Timers init
this.wakeup = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
this.wakeup.Tick += new EventHandler(wakeup_Tick);
this.wakeup.Interval = 30000;

this.time = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
this.time.Tick += new EventHandler(time_Tick);
this.time.Interval = 1000;

//Timer functions
private void wakeup_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e){
    SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS);
}

private void time_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e){
    try{
        this.window.setFechaHora(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd / MM / yyyy"), DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"));
    }catch (Exception ex){
        EscribirLogError("time_Tick " + ex.Message,false);
    }
}

//Window function
public void setFechaHora(String fecha, String hora){
    this.lblFecha.Content = fecha;
    this.lblHora.Content = hora;
}
```

Comment: You need to use a memory profiler

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsdk/2007/01/18/wpf-animations-tips-and-tricks/ `To remove animations from a specific property, use the BeginAnimation method. Specify the property being animated as the first parameter, and null as the second. This will remove all animation clocks from the property.` Does it help if you do that immediately prior to your `BeginAnimation` calls?

Comment: I'm going to try it @mjwills thanks. I have to wait until tomorrow to know if it works. I will let you know

Comment: It doesn't work mjwills, thanks on the try

Comment: Why do you need separate threads to do animation when they just use Dispatcher.Invoke to do animation on UI thread?

Comment: Btw, threads may be stopped, but you probably also need to dispose them (see if they have state transition events to listen to)

Comment: I'm really not sure why I need separate threads. This code was inherited, I assume the expected behavior was to make the animation at the same time that the other function updates the times on the window. Don't know very much about the Dispatcher, do you mean that if the three threads are calling to te Dispatcher at the end, then they're not really executing concurrently?? Then it is a nonsense, and I would change the threads for normal voids. About disposing threads, Thread class doesn't have Dispose function, and I think they are disposed when they finish its taks, isn't it?

Comment: Well, yesterday I solved it. I changed the two animation threads, invoking them as normal voids instead of creating new threads. The behavior in the user interface is practically the same, and has worked for a whole day without exceptions.
I still do not know why it does not work with threads, which are supposed to release resources at the end. Problem is solved, but i would like to know why it didn't work the other way. If anyone could explain I would be grateful

Answer (score 2):

There is not enough info from what you posted to help solve this. A memory profiler is what you need. I've had good luck with [Redgate ANTS](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/).

A few things to look at:

- Do you call an event in a loop using myEvent += blah. If so you need to -= it, else you cause a memory leak.
- Is there a Timer object created? Need to be careful with these, if you don't dereference them correctly you get a leak.

Comment: I prefer explore other options before MemoryProfiler, I have low profile at c# and VS, and I think I'm probably making some basic error about memory management.
I have 2 timer objects, which are always active, but I'm not creating new timer objects. 
Events only used on the timers. I think they are fine, but I put this info on the questio to let you see it.

Comment: From what I see those look fine. One issue is putting a += Event in the loop but you don't seem to have that.
I would look more at any timer events you have as well as loops. A slow leak could be anywhere. A fast leak is almost always in a loop or a timer.